# Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer') as response from python server while requested through an Ajax call

Tags: python, ajax, flask, multiprocessing

Facing an issue : **("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))**

Environment: PCF(OS:Linux, Instance with 3GB RAM and 8 Core of CPU)

Usecase: Need to convert larger text files into a Dataframe(20k,204) and need to do some opertaions finally saving as excel.

I have tried some 20,000 lines of text across on 200 files tried to convert all 200 text files to an excel.

ETA of execution of code is : 5 MINS.

Python code running on Flask Server.

Calling this script thru $ajax() asynchronously.

Browser: Chrome

I have done with multiprocessing using,

1. pool.map():

> ```
> pool = Pool(processes=os.cpu_count()//2,maxtasksperchild=1)                 
> s=pool.map(MainFunction, MainListFiles)
> pool.close()
> pool.join()
> del pool
> pool=None
> e=str(time.time()-st)
> s.append(e)
> ```

Calling python script using jquery Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: PythonUrl,
        data: $.param({path:'PythonCode',pythonfile:filename,data:rand}),
        beforeSend: function()
        {
          $('#loader').css('display','block');
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
          console.log(data)
          $('#loader').css('display','none');
          modal.style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = data;
        },
        error: function(x, t, m) {
          if(t==="timeout") {
              alert("got timeout");
          } else {
              alert(t);
          }
      }
    });
```

I studied that ajax will not close the connection until promise resolve right?

Then what could cause this error ? connection reset by peer, exactly what it means ?

I saw some threads like with same error but they missed the pool.join() So mp tried to close the pool while some workers are processing.but i have joined the pool properly.

**Note:** But one thing i run the same script again after this exception it ran successfully and gave proper response.

So error is due to:

1. Whether ajax close the connection , because of it didn't get response from python for much time.
2. Is browser closed the connection unexpectedly or for some reason?
3. Is this any multiprocessing exception while tried to close the pool (Because i get this error exactly at last moment where last 3 files are getting processed out of 200 files)
4. Issue usually happen because of something went wrong from client side or Server side . It says connection reset.So connection reset by server: FLASK? JavaScript ? Multiprocessing ? Browser?

This scares me really! So without understanding this can't commit this code to production. So if anybody could advise me on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround than a fix...

Using a conda env, I was having this issue with *conda* **cryptography=41.0.2**.

I don't have this issue with *conda* **cryptography=3.4.7**

Where my env was my (base)