# Python pip3 : Getting ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer when installing python-dateutil

Tags: python-3.x, pip, boto3, python-dateutil, botocore

I am trying to install botocore and boto3 package but I am getting following error

```
[]$ pip3 install --user botocore

Collecting botocore
  Using cached botocore-1.24.39-py3-none-any.whl (8.7 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore) (1.26.9)
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
     |████████                        | 61 kB 5.6 MB/s eta 0:00:01ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 437, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 461, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 505, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 216, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 344, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 184, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 391, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 343, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 469, in prepare_linked_requirement
    hashes=self._get_linked_req_hashes(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 259, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 130, in get_http_url
    link, downloader, temp_dir.path, hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 282, in _download_http_url
    for chunk in download.chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 168, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 88, in response_chunks
    decode_content=False,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 455, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError("Connection broken: %r" % e, e)
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

It is failing at installing `python-dateutil`. If I try to install this package itself separately, then also same issue.
I also tried following

```
pip3 install -i https://pypi.python.org/simple/ botocore
```

and

```
pip3 install --default-timeout=1000 botocore
```

But still it is failing with same issue.
Python version I am using is 3.7.10.
I am not able to figure out the possible reason behind this failure.

Comment: Have you tried a different network?

Comment: Could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77189386/6210975